# How to make a block in SML inside of pattern matching construction

Tags: sml

I'm a beginner in SML and still its syntax is not quite friendly to me (I'm a C# programmer). So this question may seem to you dumb.
So, I have a recursive function with pattern matching (for example factorial), which I'm going to debug and I can't get how to add `print(Int.toString(x))` to the second case. In C-like languages it'd be:

```
function fact(x) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  print(x);
  return x*fact(x-1);
}
```

How to add `print` to SML version, second case?

```
fun fact 0 = 1
  | fact x = x*fact(x-1);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's been a while, but I think you might use a semicolon, or maybe a comma. Try that?

Comment: Semicolon just ends the second case leaving no place for `print`, and with comma the function gets compiled but doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around the block and use semicolons to separate the individual expressions within it:

```
fun fact 0 = 1
  | fact x = (print (Int.toString x);
              x * fact (x-1));
```

Note that there's no need to put parentheses around `x` just to call a function on it.